# How to get slider value with subview rotation angle

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, uislider

Hi I used UISlider and rotate an image/subview based on slider value. Slider minimum value is zero and maximum value is 360. I had multiple views. With slider I am rotating the Image perfectly.

```
UIView *subView = [self.view viewWithTag:100];
subView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(slider.value * 2*M_PI / slider.maximumValue);
```

I selected another subview and next again selected the first view. So based on view angle I need to set slider value. But I am getting wrong.

```
CGAffineTransform transform = subView.transform;
CGFloat angle = atan2f(transform.b, transform.a);
[slider setValue:(angle / ((2*M_PI)/ 360)) animated:true];
```

What I did Wrong?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some struggle I got the answer. I am getting negative angle after 90. So if I got negative angle I calculated the differences between  required angle and the current angle.

```
CGFloat angle = [(NSNumber *)[subView valueForKeyPath:@"layer.transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];

if (angle < 0) {
    angle = 6.28 + angle;
}

[slider setValue:(angle*360 / (2*M_PI)) animated:true];
```